# Excel - set data range for multiple charts

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a 'dashboard' of weekly stats - with week numbers in the columns across the top, and about 70 metrics in the rows.
I want to create around 20 charts from these different metrics, but always based on the previous 4 weeks.

Can I set up these 20 charts so that it's easy to adjust the range of columns in one go, rather than changing the "Select Data" for each of the 20? I don't want to update the range of 20 charts every week!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [Excel named table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-format-tables-e81aa349-b006-4f8a-9806-5af9df0ac664) and apply filters to it. Tt automatically filters a chart input data.

You can add True/False column for easier filtering or use filter directly to WeekNumber column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the approach in [Chart the Last 12 Months](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/DynamicLast12.html).

Alternatively you could use the add-in (free) described at the end of [Change Series Formula](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/change-series-formula-improved-routines/) to modify the ranges of many charts at once.

Comment: This looks really promising - if I get it working I'll accept, thanks.